# Where can I find complete API for nodejs and it's modules?

Tags: node.js

I was just trying to make some simple tests, using nodejs's http module.

Simply said, I attempted to get all response content send by server and check length.

```
var http = require('http');

http.get(process.argv[2], function(response) {
  var dataString = "";

  response.on('data', function(data) {
    dataString += data.toString();
  });

  response.on('end', function(){
    console.log(dataString.length);
    console.log(dataString);
  });
});
```

My problem was that I have found no info about response's events on the nodejs's documentation (like 'data', 'end'; I found them on some forums, though).

Have I missed something? Should have I already know those? Where should I look for a complete nodejs and modules API?

Comment: http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_data; http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_end

Comment: I guess if you do `var dataString = ""` you do not need to call the `toString()` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the documentation for the latest stable version of node [here](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/).

For your particular case, [`http.get()`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback)/[`http.request()`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback) return a [`ClientRequest`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/http.html#http_class_http_clientrequest) object. This object emits a [`response`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/http.html#http_event_response) event when the server responds (the callback you pass to `http.get()`/`http.request()` is a shortcut for adding a `response` event handler). The argument passed to `response` event handlers is of type [`IncomingMessage`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/http.html#http_http_incomingmessage). `IncomingMessage` is a [Readable stream](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable), that is where the 'data' and 'end' events in particular come from.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation:  http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_incomingmessage

> An IncomingMessage object is created by http.Server or http.ClientRequest and passed as the first argument to the 'request' and 'response' event respectively. It may be used to access response status, headers and data.
>
> It implements the Readable Stream interface, as well as the following additional events, methods, and properties

That means that events for data and what not are part of the ReadableStream, which can be found here:  http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable  Other events are as-listed on the http.IncomingMessage documentation.